# Help I broke terminal

Tags: command-line

I tried the below "tip" trying to learn different things I could do with terminal and it does not work. Now I get an error message when I open terminal. How can I delete what I did? 
Thank you!

> **Learn Linux commands**
>
> Open the GNOME terminal and run the following command:
>
> ```
> echo ‘man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n 1`’ >> ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> Now, whenever you open a terminal, you will be greeted by a man page
>   of a random command. It’s a nice way to learn about new commands.

Comment: The error appear because you user these quotes: `‘<command>’` instead of these:  `'<command>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Nautilus (file Manager). Type `<CTRL>-L` to make the navigation bar editable. (Note that `<CTRL>-L` means you must press the Control key and the letter `L` on your keyboard simultaneously).
2. In the navigation bar, type `/etc/skel/` and press `<ENTER>`.
3. Type `<CTRL>-H` to view hidden files.
4. Right click on the file named `.bashrc`.
5. Select Copy from the context menu that pops up.
6. Click `Home` in the left navigation pane in Nautilus. This will show all the files in your home folder.
7. Right click on a blank space in the files area. Select Paste from the context menu that pops up.
8. You will be asked to replace file `.bashrc` ? Click the `Replace` button to confirm.
9. Type `<CTRL>-H` to not show hidden files.
10. Now try to start Terminal and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

1. First, open the file manager and go to your user folder.
2. Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, which should show you the hidden files.
3. You should then be able to find a file named `.bashrc`, which you can open with a text editor.
4. Remove the line referring to `ls /usr/bin ...` and you should be good.